# I'm trying to get the innerHTML function in Javascript to work

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I want the heating answer to appear next to the Heating Surface (mm) but I can't make it work. I only get the following error message from the chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

I know everything else works because I added an alert box, I need the innerHTML to work though.

Here is the html:

```
 <html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pipeheaterfunction.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr><td>Inner Diameter (mm):</td>
<td><input id="dia" onkeypress="pipeheater();"></td>

<tr><td>Pipe Thickness (mm):</td>
<td><input id="thi" onkeypress="pipeheater();"></td>

<tr><th>Calculate heater:</th>
<td><button onclick="pipeheater();">Calculate</button></td></tr>

<tr><td>Heating Surface(mm):</td>
<td><span class="output" id="surface"></span></td></tr>
</table>

</body>


</html>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
function pipeheater(){ //dia is the inner diameter of a pipe, thi is the pipe thickness

var dia = document.getElementById("dia").value;
var thi = document.getElementById("thi").value;
var hsur; //hsur is the heating surface required for a certain pipe in mm

hsur = 5*Math.sqrt(((dia-thi)*thi)/2);

var surface = hsur;


if(surface>0){
surface.innerHTML=surface.toFixed(1);
alert(surface.toFixed(1));
}


}

window.onload=pipeheater();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your script. At first, when setting

```
window.onload = pipeheater();
```

`pipeheater` is invoked immediately, it's not waiting `window.onload` to be fired, and you get an error when trying to read a value of yet-non-existing element. You can fix this like this:

```
window.onload = pipeheater;
```

Secondly, you try to use `innerHTML` of `hsur`, which is a number. You need to define a variable for the actual HTML element. Below is your fixed code.

```
function pipeheater() {
    var dia = document.getElementById("dia").value,
        thi = document.getElementById("thi").value,
        hsur = 5 * Math.sqrt(((dia - thi) * thi) / 2),
        surface = document.getElementById("surface");

    if (hsur > 0) {
        surface.innerHTML = hsur.toFixed(1);
        alert(hsur.toFixed(1));
    }
}

window.onload = pipeheater;
```

You can check how this works at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bht5Z/). I'd recommend you to validate values of `dia` and `thi` before making any calculations with them. Also using `onchange` instead of `onkeypress` might be more comfortable for users, and would give you more reliable results.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define "surface".

`var surfaceSPAN = document.getElementById("surface");`

You can then do:

`surfaceSPAN.innerHTML = surface.toFixed(1);`

Do note that you cannot use the variable name "surface" twice in one script, as they would overrule eachother and you'd have no variable result.

Comment: Though this is also correct, it's not answering the question ; ).

Comment: Because it doesn't fix the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: The rest seemed valid to me; I could put up a JSFiddle and check if any of those earlier fields are invalid; but from what I read it's not. Just by glancing over it I could see that the surface var was undefined and didn't contain a reference to the original <span id="surface"></span>.

Comment: `window.onload=pipeheater();` causes the error, like flav said in his comment. Add that to your answer, and earn some rep : ).

Comment: The only reason I could see why you wouldn't need to use the () is when he defined the function as var pipeheater = function(); So I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: Umh... `pipeheater()` is executed instantly, it's not waiting for `window.onload` to be fired. Basically OP sets `window.onload = undefined`.

Comment: Ah like that. But isn't setting `window.onload=pipeheater;` just setting it to something that doesn't exist and therefore does nothing? He doesn't actually need to load that function in order to use it; only if he wanted it to fire upon loading. Because there are no standard values; he probably does not.

Comment: But `pipeheater` exists! You can see it's declared above. It's name is a reference to the function itself, which should be assigned to `window.onload` property. In its current form `pipeheater` should _return_ a function, which then will be assigned...